# A triangle with given vertex $B (2, -7)$, height and median from different verticies are given. How to find the A and C coordinates?

Tags: geometry

I have a problem in which I have a random triangle given Vertex $B(2,-7)$. I have the equation of a height from $A:3x+y+11=0$ and the equation of a median from $C: x+2y+7=0$. How to find the points $A$ and $C$. So far I managed to find just $C$ but still can't figure out how to find $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $BC$-side is the perpendicular to $h_A$ through $B$, hence you may find $C$ by intersecting $x+2y+7=0$ and $x-3y-23 = 0$. Now $A$ lies on $h_A$ and the midpoint between $A$ and $B$ must lie on the line $x+2y+7=0$, hence if $A=(x,y)$,
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 3x+y+11 &=& 0, \\ \left(\frac{x+2}{2}\right)+2\left(\frac{y-7}{2}\right)+7&=&0.\end{array}\right.$$
Can you solve it?

Comment: It turned out quite more simple than I initially thought it would be :-) Thanks a lot!